# How to control lifx bulbs by C++ in computer

Tags: c++, api, http, lifx

i'm a new guys here.And actually my programming language is basic.><
But i have a project about to control the wifi bulbs by C++ in computer.
And i don't know how to start to do it.

- Can anyone give me some suggestion?
- What should i started to do first?
- Or how to improve my programming's knowledge  about this project?

I have been downloaded the lifx http api in my computer. But i didn't know what is that mean... and didn't know when i have api what should i do next. i haven't done this before ..

Really thanks for your help !!

Comment: First, make a requirements statement, details are important.  Secondly, research the web on "c++ wifi".  Also research "lifx bulb control".  Lastly, learn C++ from a reputable source.

Comment: ok really thanks for ur help!

Comment: Off-topic (since asking for resource recommendation) but read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) and [Programming Using C++](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html)

Answer (score 1):

If your programming skills are basic I would never start with C++ but if that's not an option I can suggest you to go here:

https://github.com/kalimaul/lifx-api

And start working with it, at least you won't have to start from scratch.